# HTML5 local SQL database - How to execute a sequence a series of database transactions where order matters?

Tags: iphone, html, safari, webkit, local-storage

I'm working on an HTML5-based web application that will make use of a local SQL database.

When the app starts up, it needs to do the following (simplified, but roughly correct):

1. Check to see if the database exists; if not, create it
2. Check to make sure if table A exist; if not, create it
3. Check to make sure if table B exist; if not, create it
4. Check to make sure if table C exist; if not, create it
5. Check to see what data is available in each table A; if it's empty, pre-populate it with default values
6. Check to see what data is available in each table B; if it's empty, pre-populate it with default values
7. Check to see what data is available in each table C; if it's empty, pre-populate it with default values
8. Render the UI based on the data retrieved in steps 5-7

As I understand it, each executeSQL transaction is asynchronous.

In this case - certain steps must be complete before other steps can be executed. In other words, #1 must be complete before anything else can happen. Next, #2, #3, and #4 don't need to be executed serially - but #2 needs to be complete before #5, #3 needs to be complete before #6, etc.

This must be a pretty common challenge. So, what's the best way to code a series of dependent SQL transactions like this?

For what it's worth - this app is targeting iPhones exclusively, so I don't need to worry about browser quirks, or check for the existence of this functionality. But, a cross-browser solution is always preferable.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

executeSql takes a data handler callback function as argument. The data handler function is executed once the query has executed and gives you access to the result set. Just execute the next query in the data handler of the previous query.

Comment: JB - That's what I was thinking too. But I see two problems with this... 1) What happens if you have MANY transaction steps? Step #2 gets handled in the callback for step #1; Step #3 gets handled in the callback for step #2, etc. After several steps - the code gets REAL messy, and VERY inflexible (e.g., what happens if I later decide to modify the sequence?) Also - in my case - I don't have a single serial sequence. E.g., step #5 depends on step #2, step #6 depends on step #3, step #8 depends on steps #5-7. I'm not sure if callbacks can handle this complexity...

Comment: I would make it completely serial 1, then 2, then 3, etc., as you would do it with blocking calls. It will greatly simplify things. Only optimize if there is a performance problem, but I doubt it would make a difference to execute some steps in parallel, because the underlying implementation will preobably serialize the queries anyway. Having one SQL call the next one makes the code not so messy. Just make one function per query, and not one function for the whole process.